# phase modulation in LabVIEW

Tags: labview, modulation

is there a way to implement phase modulation and demodulation in LabVIEW(using NI USRP and without MathScript). I cant seem to be able to convert the block diagrams into useful circuits.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free toolkit for this purpose https://www.ni.com/pl-pl/support/downloads/software-products/download.labview-modulation-toolkit.html#